# Meteor: Static HTML page as root

Tags: meteor

I made a meteor app, added a /public directory full of .html, .jpeg, etc...

It all works nicely just like that except that going to my domain's root doesn't show anything; I have to type in /index.html.

How can I make my domain root go to public/index.html?

Answer (score 0):

Meteor wasn't really made with serving static content (in the form of HTML) in mind. The `public` folder is really used to serve things like the favicon and maybe an image here or there (http://docs.meteor.com/#structuringyourapp).

While you could technically do something like:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  window.location = 'index.html';
}
```

It's not really how it's supposed to work. And this brings other problems, such as making sure this only works on the `/` route.

A far better solution is to have `nginx` stand in front of a running instance of Meteor and serve static content directly.

It all really depends on why you're attempting to serve `index.html` like that. If it's for SEO purposes, just use normal Meteor templates (and routing) and use the `spiderable` (http://docs.meteor.com/#spiderable) package.

Answer (score 0):

What Dino suggests is definitely true, but from your description ("my domain root doesn't show anything") it sounds like you might just want to put your index.html into your client folder and edit it to accommodate the way meteor likes it, namely removing all doctype declarations and the html tags. Afterwards you should be seeing something when you go to your domain root.

If you want to serve several different .html files, you could check out the [iron-router](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router), which allows you to do server side routing.

Answer (score 0):

It's not standard practice to use `mywebsite.com/public/index.html`.

One reason is your site won't render the index page without navigating to `mywebsite.com/public`.

But if you really want to do this, simply add a public folder within your public folder.

`public/public/index.html`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like for what you're trying to do you'll want to put the index.html file into the form of a meteor template and then define that template as the one to be used for the '/' route in your routes file.

For example your template would look like:

```
<tementer code hereplate name="home">
  <h1>My Home Page</h1>
</template>
```

And in your router file:

```
Router.route('/', function() {
 this.render('home');
 this.layout('homeLayout');
});
```

This is assuming that you're using Iron Router and have a separate template file that you're using for the layout. If you need a further example let me know and I'll be happy to help.